# Adding BarButton in rightBarButtonItems

Tags: ios, rightbarbuttonitem

I have created 4 BarButtons with Image and when i added to navigation bar. It shows large gap in between the items and how can remove the gap between the image.

Comment: You need to post the code you used to add those buttons. A snapshot will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by maintaining image insets like this:-

```
UIBarButtonItem *demoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(saveStyle)];

demoButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0, -60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Item would help u to maintain ur gap. Add your images to button.

```
UIBarButtonItem *fixedItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    fixedItem.width = 10.;  

    UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0., 0., 44., 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView: button1];

    UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46., 0., 44., 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView: button2];

    UIButton *button3 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95., 0., 44., 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView: button3];

    NSArray *itemArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: barButton1, fixedItem, barButton2, fixedItem, barButton3, nil];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = itemArray;
```